# Java file Formatting proper order

Tags: java, file, logic, formatter

I am writing a program which requires the opening of a file, adding to it, and then closing it. For some reason when I try to do so, I get a nullPointerException.
Here is what I have in the main class:

```
public static filer f = new filer();
```

and then:

```
f.addStuff("hi");
f.closeFile();
```

now here is what I have in the file class, which is where I think the problem is right now: 
public class filer {

```
private static Formatter f;//to add to file
private static Scanner s; //to read file
public static File file;
private static boolean ftf = false;

public static void openFile() {
    try{ //exception handling
         file = new File("jibberish.txt");
          //shows if file created
         System.out.println("File created: "+ ftf);
         // deletes file from the system
         file.delete();
         // delete() is invoked
         System.out.println("delete() method is invoked");
         // tries to create new file in the system
         ftf = file.createNewFile();
         // print
         System.out.println("File created: "+ ftf);

        Formatter f = new Formatter(file);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        FileReader r = new FileReader(file);
        /*
        f = new Formatter("jibberish.txt");  //will automatically create jibberish.txt if no exist
        s = new Scanner("jibberish.txt");
        */  //don't us these because scanner will take type string, easier to clear all other way
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){ 
        System.out.println("Trouble reading from the file: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void addStuff(String toAdd){
    f.format("%s ", toAdd);
    System.out.printf("%s added", toAdd);
}

public static void closeFile(){ //need to do this to avoid errors
    f.close();
    s.close();
}
```

the rest of the class works, i have all the proper imports and stuff
oh and of course here is what comes out of the console:

```
File created: false
delete() method is invoked
File created: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at filer.addStuff(filer.java:48)
at transMain.main(transMain.java:40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `NullPointerException` because when you call the `addStuff` method, `f` has not been initialized and is therefore `null`. Calling a method on a reference to a `null` object will result in a `NullPointerException`.

The problem is with the following line in `openFile`. You are creating a new local variable called `f` which hides the field named `f` declared at class level :

```
Formatter f = new Formatter(file);
```

Change the above line as follows so that the class level field `f` is the one that is initialized in `openFile`:

```
f = new Formatter(file);
```

Comment: ah ok, I thought It was being initialized with f.openFile();  ?

Comment: nevermind, you are correct.  I have no idea what I just said in the comment above. Thanks so much, works now!

Comment: @Bagel Don't forget to upvote the answer and accept it if you feel that it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: yeah sorry, i just had to wait before I could hit check